# Constructing an explicit isomorphism between automorphism group of bijective $F$-linear mappings and group of intertible $n \times n$ matrices

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm going over some class notes:

> In the literature, sometimes a representation of $G$ over $F$ is defined as a pair $(V, \rho)$ where $V$ is a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space and $\rho: G \to \text{Aut}\left(V \right)$ is a group homomorphism into the group of $F$-linear automorphisms of $V$.

A group representation was initially defined as a group homomorphism between a group $G$ and the general linear group $GL_n(F)$. The statement above is essentially saying  that $GL_n(F) \cong \text{Aut}\left(V \right)$ but I am having a little difficulty constructing the explicit isomorphism even though I have an intuitive idea of why this is the case.

If we let $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ be an $F$-basis for $V$ and $T \in \text{Aut}\left(V \right)$, then we can write $T(v_j)= \sum_{k=1}^n a_{jk} v_k$ where the scalars $a_{jk} \in F$ can be put into a matrix to represent a matrix in $GL_n(F)$.

From here, I am having difficulty thinking a bijective function $\varphi: GL_n(F) \to \text{Aut}(V)$ that sends invertible $n \times n$ matrices to the group of $F$-linear bijective linear transformations $T: V \to V$. How do we write it explictly?

Comment: You mean, something other than "left multiplication of each (column) vector of $V$ written in terms of the chosen basis, by $T$"?

Comment: Each vector of $V$ has a unique representation (say, as a column vector) in terms of the chosen basis. Pre-multiplying a vector $x$ by the matrix $T$ gives you a vector $Tx = y$ (say). Thus, $T$ defines a mapping from $V$ to itself, which is obviously linear, and therefore an endomorphism of $V$. If $T$ is invertible, then the endomorphism is bijective (for $x = T^{-1}y$), and is therefore an automorphism of $V$.